# Вопрос со временем и списками

Tags: python, время, словари

Я хотел совершить эксперимент небольшой: создать список из n-го количества элементов, в каждом из которого будет отображаться значение time.time(). Однако, консоль выводит одинаковые значения. Как сделать так, чтобы каждое значение было больше предыдущего в списке? И как поступить, если оно, к примеру, является правой стороной элемента в словаре?

```
import time

n = [{'t': time.time(), 'n': 'one'},{'t': time.time(), 'n':'two'}]

print(n[0]['t'], n[0]['n'])
print(n[1]['t'], n[1]['n'])
```

Comment: Время проставляется в список в момент создания списка, список создается практически мгновенно, поэтому время проставляется одинаковое. `Как сделать так, чтобы каждое значение было больше предыдущего в списке?` - добавить какое-то timedelta к левому времени, результат записать во второй словарь. Или перед созданием второго элемента сделать небольшую паузу. Все зависит от конкретной задачи.

Comment: @insolor у меня версия 3.9 python. Я просто видел, что у кого-то была ранняя версия, и с time.time() он смог сделать так, чтобы второе число отличалось от первого, пусть и чуть-чуть

Comment: При запуске в Google Colab у меня отличается в последней цифре: 1613628012.0781045 one
1613628012.0781047 two

Comment: Ну, можно взять медленный компьютер, поставить на архивацию какой-то большой файл (чтобы загрузить процессор), одновременно запустить ваш скрипт, тогда два времени возможно будут более заметно отличаться. Но все равно не понятен смысл этого.

Comment: @parrothi, проверил на Python 3.9, дает результат `[{'t': 1613628464.2773955, 'n': 'one'}, {'t': 1613628464.2773979, 'n': 'two'}]` - второе время больше первого. Возможно у вас просто "слишком быстрый" компьютер:)

Comment: 1613633835.2811828 one
1613633835.2811832 two хоть на 0.0000004 с., но разница есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить такой немного смешной способ:

```
import time

k = 3
n = [{'t': time.sleep(0.1), 't': time.time(), 'n': i} for i in range(1, k+1)]
print(n)
```

Вывод:

```
[{'t': 1613628305.7483826, 'n': 1}, {'t': 1613628305.8485167, 'n': 2}, {'t': 1613628305.9487169, 'n': 3}]
```

Прикол в том, что если при создании словаря есть повторяющиеся ключи, то сохраняется только последний. Таким образом, я добавил паузу в создание словаря, при этом результат выполнения функции`time.sleep()` (`None`) потом отбрасывается.

Comment: Разве есть гарантия, что сначала посчитается `sleep()`, а не `time()`?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов В последних версиях питона ведь есть гарантия сохранения порядка ключей? Думаю, из-за этого и порядок действий тоже должен сохраниться. Хотя не факт, вы в общем случае правы. Для гарантии нужно выносить создание словаря в отдельную функцию и там делать нормально `time.sleep`. А лучше добавлять `timedelta`, конечно. В общем это чисто по приколу всё.